# Is there a version of Ubuntu that is compatible with a windows 8 Digiland Tablet PC

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Model:  DL801W
Processor:  Intel(R)  Atom(TM)  CPU Z3735F@1.33GHz 
RAM: 1.00GB
System: 32-bit,  x64-based Processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Ubuntu 32-bit and Ubuntu 64-bit (desktop / server, in any flavour) will run on your tablet, however your tablet's specifications are a little low (an I'd guess the graphic card, which is another important piece of hardware to take into account, is either low-end or integrated).

I'd suggest you to install a lightweight version of Ubuntu such as [Lubuntu Desktop 14.04.2 LTS 64-bit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu/LTS) (which is the current long-term-support release and which will be supported with updates until about mid-2017) or [Lubuntu Desktop 15.04 64-bit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) (which is the latest release and which will be supported with updates until about early 2016).

As the welcome excerpt states on [Lubuntu's home page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu):

> Lubuntu is targeted at PC and laptop users running on low-spec hardware that, in most cases, just don't have enough resources for all the bells and whistles of the "full-featured" mainstream distributions.

Comment: @Kove No problem, however if this answer helped you please consider accepting it; have a read at [this](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Done  and done. @kos